# ADYEN 3.1.2 (Drop In Method) iOS

Tags: ios, swift5, adyen

hi does anyone implemented adyen droppin feature in iOS swift 5 . they have no example on GitHub so it is hard for me to get the logic. Can anyone help please

Comment: They have latest version Adyen 3.1.2, not 3.2.1

Answer (score 3):

You should check the full page of github. hey have given required information for documentation. At the end they have gave Complete Documentation link.

**Complete Documentation:** https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/ios

where you can see iOS option in left menu and there are following two option available.

**ios -> drop-in:** https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/ios/drop-in

**ios -> components:** https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/ios/components